# How are different circuit form factors (SODIMM, PCIe) designed and manufactured?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, system-on-chip

Using  recent technologies, System on Chips (SoC) and other type of single board computers are manufactured on compact small boards. A common form-factor SoCs is a DIMM based or even PCIe form factors. where the entire system is laid down on the board, and the socket expands and gives access to the pins of the SoC.

1. What type of software is used to create these? for example, can you make a SODIMM based PCB on Eagle or KiCAD, or are there special programs?
2. How would one manufacture these? is it possible to manufacture these form factors in small quantities the was most traditional PCBs are manufactured?

I have designed a single board computer that i would like to make a DIMM style prototype for, any good books you would recommend ?

Comment: These are just PCBs. Design in PCB design tools, assemble in a PCB fab house.

Comment: They just follow standards. There’s organizations based on a conglomeration of companies. You can use any software for any type of interface. I work at HP so I have access to free documentation because HP is part of a PCI organization that defines standards and design for PCIe devices. The same can be said about DIMM, SATA, and other serial interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just PCBs. You can just make them. You should find the standard measurements so that you can make sure your PCB has the right measurements to fit into the slot. Maybe someone has a template file for you, but if not, you can make it yourself from scratch.

The connector style is called an *edge connector* or *card edge connector*. Your PCB software should have a footprint for one. It should work as a normal connector, except you don't have to solder any component there because the PCB itself is the connector.

Some manufacturers will be able to dip the edge of the PCB into a gold plating machine - just the edge - so you can get a better connection without having to gold-plate the entire board. They might also be able to bevel the edge of the connector, which makes it easier to insert into the slot, since the part you put into the slot is thinner and then it self-centers as you push it in.

> What type of software is used to create these?

Any PCB software.

> for example, can you make a SODIMM based PCB on Eagle or KiCAD,

Yes.

> or are there special programs?

Maybe - I don't know.

> How would one manufacture these?

They are just normal PCBs, except for the edge plating and bevelling, but most PCB manufacturers won't have a problem with that (they might cost extra though!). For your own experiment, I *think* you can afford to skip these steps, but don't quote me on that.

> is it possible to manufacture these form factors in small quantities the was most traditional PCBs are manufactured?

Yes, they're just normal PCBs.

> I have designed a single board computer that i would like to make a DIMM style prototype for, any good books you would recommend ?

[Buying recommendations are off-topic here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you very much. As soon as i started looking up "Edge Connector" i got lots of great resources. Much appreciated